# time complexity of Balanced Binary Tree code

Tags: recursion

```
public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) return true;

    int left = getHeight(root.left);
    int right = getHeight(root.right);
    if (Math.abs(left - right) > 1) return false;

    return isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right);
}

private int getHeight(TreeNode n) {
    if (n == null) return 0;

    return Math.max(getHeight(n.left), getHeight(n.right)) + 1;
}
```

This is the code from leetcode http://discuss.leetcode.com/questions/276/balanced-binary-tree 
since the discussion is closed there. I just want to ask why they said this code time complexity is nlogn not O(n)
Thanks

Comment: check this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-determine-if-a-binary-tree-is-balanced/

Comment: Because getHeight is not O(1)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the complexity of `getHeight()` is O(logn). And in `isBalanced()`, it's a recursive function that will traverse the tree once at complexity of O(n), while at each node it call `getHeight()` function. So the total complexity is O(nlogn).